# Price comparison statistics and data visualisation

Tags: anova, data-visualization, multiple-comparisons, paired-comparisons, z-score

I'm getting into learning statistics and was hoping you could give me some pointers on where to go with this experiment.

Basically I'm trying to compare prices for same/similar items across a variety of shops and then running some statistics to understand the differences and finding a way to visualise the data.

So here's a sample of made up data (but would like it work for several hundred items):

\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
  &Milk &Eggs &Cream &Potatoes &Cabbage &Carrots \\
\hline
Supermarket1 &49 &99 &90 &150 &99 &100 \\
\hline
Supermarket2 &52 &206 &72 &220 &125 &160 \\
\hline
Supermarket3 &39 &129 &85 &39 &35 &39 \\
\hline
Supermarket4 &48 &105 &99 &136 &85 &29 \\
\hline
\end{array}
So we've got the usual descriptive statistics like mean and median prices for each item (last two rows) and the mean prices across all items per supermarket (last column).

\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
  &Milk &Eggs &Cream &Potatoes &Cabbage &Carrots &Mean \\
\hline
Supermarket1 &49 &99 &90 &150 &99 &100 &97.83 \\
\hline
Supermarket2 &52 &206 &72 &220 &125 &160 &139.17 \\
\hline
Supermarket3 &39 &129 &85 &39 &35 &39 &49.5 \\
\hline
Supermarket4 &48 &105 &99 &136 &85 &29 &83.4 \\
\hline
Median &48.5 &105 &87.5 &150 &99 &69.5 \\
\hline
Mean &47 &136.67 &86.5 &168.67 &86.33 &82 \\
\hline
\end{array}
If I wanted to do more comparisons between supermarkets what would be the best stats to calculate? I've been thinking of using Z-scores to compare values with their counterparts in each column. I was also thinking of using the last column means to run a pearson correlation with the ranking of best supermarkets in the country to see if their mean prices correlate with their ranking – with a hypothesis that the top ranked supermarkets will have the higher prices.

In addition to this I was toying with t-tests and ANOVA stats but I'm not sure how this would work on this kind of data when there are gaps due to not every item being stocked by each store.

Any advice on where to proceed with this to get as much information when comparing one shop to all the others would be gratefully received – I know what I've thought of so far is pretty simple, but I'm still learning :)

Comment: Thank you for the welcome - I look forward to getting involved. :)